# Node express: not able to access data after query execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a simple custom module in which all methods are supposed to return database records.

I am getting all records after running a query but when I try to assign those records to some variable then it says `null`. Not sure what is going on.
Here is my custom module code:

```
module.exports = {

    mydata: {},
    all: function (req, res, next) {

        var posts = null;

        con.query("SELECT post_id,title, body from `posts`", function (err, rows, fileds) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error' + err);
            }
            posts = rows[0]; // assigned object object to posts but not working


            console.log('names' + posts);
        });

        console.log('my posts' + posts); // it says null/empty 
        return posts;       // empty return

    },
```

I am calling all methods like this in my route:

```
console.log("admin.js :" + postModel.all());
```

All are empty or null. Please guide or suggest. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using async & await plus it's best practice to wrap the code in try catch, any pending promise will be resolved at the .then method or any error will be caught at the .catch of the caller/final function:

/ * Handler (or) Service (or) Whatever */

```
const FetchDataFromDB = require('../');

/* caller Function */
let fetchDataFromDB = new FetchDataFromDB();
fetchDataFromDB.getDataFromDB()
    .then((res) => console.log(res))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

/* DB Layer */

```
class FetchDataFromDB {

    /* Method to get data from DB */
    async getDataFromDB() {

        const getQuery = "SELECT post_id,title, body from `posts`";
        try {
            let dbResp = await con.query(getQuery);
            if (dbResp.length) {
                //Do some logic on dbResp
            }
            return dbResp;
        } catch (error) {
            throw (error);
        }
    }
}

module.exports = FetchDataFromDB;
```

Comment: @sarinivas thanks for your reply.I am using module.exports in which I am having list of function/property as you can.How I can add callback getDataFromDB in module export? or is there any good way to do that.Please guide.

Comment: Let me check it.

Comment: I've suggested async/await as these days in javascript it would be better if you use this for synchronous operation & seems like your code is just for a single file & if you really need something to be implemented in callback at this place " console.log("admin.js :" + postModel.all()); " ---> try to do : function getData(cb)
{postModel.all((err, docs) => { if (err) {  return cb(null, null); } else { return cb(null, docs); }})}

Answer (score 1):

Welcome my friend to the world of Asynchronous function.
In your code the

`console.log('my posts' + posts);` and `return posts;`

are executing before the callback assigns values to the `posts` variable.

Also restrict yourself from using `var` instead use `let` for declaring variable works better without error for scoped functions.

Here below:

- The `async` keyword declares that the function is asynchronous.
- The `await` keyword basically says that lets first get the result and then move on to next statement/line. All `awaits` should be done inside an `async` functions only.

```
module.exports = {

mydata: {},
  all: async function (req, res, next) { //Let this be an asynchronous function
      try{
         let [rows, fields] = await con.query("SELECT post_id,title, body from `posts`");
         //let us await for the query result so stay here until there is result

         let posts = rows[0]; // assign first value of row to posts variable now
         console.log('my posts' + posts);
         return posts;
      }catch(err){
         return err;
      }
  },
}
```

Please take time reading up nature of Asynchronous, Non-blocking in JavaScript and how to handle them with Promises or Async/await (my personal choice).

Comment: #Atih Shakya
@Atih Shakya

By the ways above code didn't worked and throwing warning 
Promise { <pending> }
(node:2480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable

Comment: By the way is this a router?
Where is the response going?

Comment: Please check if the updated answer and reply to me if it's working or not

Comment: In file routes/index.js am calling the method  like this 
const myModel = require('../localmodule');
myModel.all()

Comment: what do you mean ? .php file?

Comment: postModel.all().then(data =>{
  console.log(data);
});

could you try this instead and give me feedback?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192924/discussion-between-peter-and-atish-shakya).